# Activate autoplay on HTML popup video player

Tags: html, video, video-player

I have bought an HTML template which has a button to play a video in a popup. This is the code:

```
<div class="video-play-button">
<a href="https://xxxxx/yyyyy/zzz.mp4" class="video  video-play mfp-iframe" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video-popup">
<span class="ti-control-play"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

the video file is stored in AWS S3. When I click on the button, the pop-up with the video player appears but I still need to press Play in order to see the video.

I would like to get the video starting automatically. I know that if the video was on youtube I could use something like `...?autoplay=1` in the URL, but I really need the file on S3

Comment: can you replace the link with a video tag? and add autoplay and muted attributes?

[MDN video tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: unfortunately I can't, it needs to be triggered by a link